# How to test fast application switching in Mango?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, fast-app-switching

I want to test out whether fast application switching is working in Mango.  I start the app from the IDE, it kicks off the emulator.  I then move away from the application (by clicking the Windows button on the emulator).  Then I go back into the application from the phone.

However, the IDE loses connection to the emulator and I can't debug what happens when the app is reactivated.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you upgraded to the Beta 2 Refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My debug session seems to continue working.  I started debugging an app, tap the start button on the emulator, which took me back to the start screen, then I hit the back button on the emulator, my app came back, and I hit a button where a break point was inserted, and I hit the break point.  Is this the order you're doing things in with the emulator?

Just to be sure, I just did the same with using tap/hold on the back button, and it worked as well.

Comment: I see what happened.  When I followed your scenario, it worked as well.  I did the following: tapped the Start button, the tapped the Arrow button, which took me to the list of apps, then tapped my App.  It started a new instance of the app.  What results do you get in that scenario?

Comment: When you hit the back button and exit your app, that will end the debug session, so your system was working as designed.  Just remember that the back button exiting an app is just like closing a Windows app, and it will no longer be in the back stack, either.  Glad I could help!